# Cypress: How to check button url?

Tags: url, cypress

I want to check that buttons urls are contain specific urls (without clicking on them), is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the list of supported assertions: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai

You can use `have.attr` to test the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag.

For example:

```js
cy.get('a.my-link').should('have.attr', 'href', 'https://example.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to match just a portion of a link's url you can chain assertions as seen here in the example recipes:  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/07600edbcd7bcdd89e717ff801c74a79d1c006a3/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links/cypress/integration/tab_handling_anchor_links_spec.js#L44

```
cy.get('#users').should('have.attr', 'href').and('include', 'users.html')
```